# Azure Notification Hub doesn't work for ios

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

[Following this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-push/) I created azure notification hub and added to my app registation. My app register for remote notification successful and when I tried to get registered device on back end, I successful got my installation id.

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
MobileServiceClient client = QSTodoService.DefaultService.GetClient;

const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

JObject templates = new JObject();
templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
{
    {"body", templateBodyAPNS}
};

// Register for push with your mobile app
var push = client.GetPush();
push.RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);
}
```

But when try to send notification

```
        // Get the settings for the server project.
        HttpConfiguration config = this.Configuration;
        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings =
            this.Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        // Get the Notification Hubs credentials for the Mobile App.
        string notificationHubName = settings.NotificationHubName;
        string notificationHubConnection = settings
            .Connections[MobileAppSettingsKeys.NotificationHubConnectionString].ConnectionString;

        // Create a new Notification Hub client.
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
        .CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);

        // Sending the message so that all template registrations that contain "messageParam"
        // will receive the notifications. This includes APNS, GCM, WNS, and MPNS template registrations.
        Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        templateParams["messageParam"] = "some message";

        try
        {
            var result = hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            config.Services.GetTraceWriter()
                .Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
        }
```

Result said "successful sent: 0, failed sent: 0.

What can be the reason of this trouble?

**Update**

I don't think the problem with sertificate or provisioning profile as when I'm trying to send notification via azure - it send. (though I don't receive, but it's already another problem).
[image]

**Update 2**

I've also tried to send to registered tag,

```
string payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}";
List<string> tags = new List<string> {"testTag"};
hub.CreateAppleTemplateRegistrationAsync(token,payload,tags);

Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            templateParams["messageParam"] = "message";
var res = hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, tags);
```

and apple native notification, but result was the same.

```
hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(payload);
```

BTW, notificationId is empty and state notification shows as 'Enqueued'.

Comment: Have you verified that you're using the "Listen, Manage, Send" connection string (from Azure) for notificationHubConnection?

Comment: Yes, I'am using FullSharedAccessSignature for connection

Comment: Are you really sure you are using the correct provisioning profile for you application? If not nothing will be received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going through tutorial from scratch, recreated certificate, provisioning profile, notification hub etc, and now it works.